# angularfire 2: Error "Unhandled Promise rejection: TypeError: Cannot read property"

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I tried an example app to connect to Firebase

In my Main.ts I wrote this:

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent, environment } from './app/';
import { FIREBASE_PROVIDERS, defaultFirebase, firebaseAuthConfig, AuthProviders, AuthMethods } from 'angularfire2';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

bootstrap(AppComponent,[
  FIREBASE_PROVIDERS,
  defaultFirebase({
    apiKey: "MYKEY",
    authDomain: "MYDOMAIN.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://MYDOMAN.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "MYDOMAIN.appspot.com",
  }),
  firebaseAuthConfig({
    provider: AuthProviders.Password,
    method: AuthMethods.Popup
  })
]);
```

EDIT: here is the component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/'

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
  directives: [ LoginComponent ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Please Login to the App';
}
```

But when is start my App with "ng serve" and call the URL , I get an error called:

> zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'FacebookAuthProvider' of undefined
>         at Object.eval (http://localhost:4200/vendor/angularfire2/providers/firebase_sdk_auth_backend.js:24:43)
>         at eval (http://localhost:4200/vendor/angularfire2/providers/firebase_sdk_auth_backend.js:108:4)
>         at eval (http://localhost:4200/vendor/angularfire2/providers/firebase_sdk_auth_backend.js:109:3)
>         at Object.eval (http://localhost:4200/vendor/angularfire2/angularfire2.js:33:35)
>     Evaluating
>   http://localhost:4200/vendor/angularfire2/providers/firebase_sdk_auth_backend.js
>     Evaluating http://localhost:4200/vendor/angularfire2/angularfire2.js
>     Evaluating http://localhost:4200/app/login/login.component.js
>     Evaluating http://localhost:4200/app/login/index.js     Evaluating
>   http://localhost:4200/app/app.component.js    Evaluating
>   http://localhost:4200/app/index.js    Evaluating
>   http://localhost:4200/main.js     Error loading
>   http://localhost:4200/main.js ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ;
>   Value: Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'FacebookAuthProvider'
>   of undefined(…)

Any ideas?

Comment: What does your `AppComponent` look like?

Comment: `Main.ts` file is fine, give us the code with `FacebookAuthProvider` component and service if you have one.

Comment: @Michael i edited the post.

Comment: @JS_astronauts : The Code is here : https://github.com/angular/angularfire2 , its in the Libary

Comment: do you have these in stalled correctly ?     "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "firebase": "^3.0.5"

Comment: Damn it , i had an old Version (2.4.2) the newest Versions runs without Problems.. thank you ! @JS_astronauts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, it appears that this error occurs when using the Firebase 2.x SDK instead of the Firebase 3.x SDK which is required by AngularFire2.