# Angular 2 with Firebase EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: A network error has occurred

Tags: angularjs, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am trying to use Firebase auth feature in an Angular 2 project. These are the packages I have pulled in in my `package.json` file:

```
"firebase": "^3.7.1",
"angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
```

The component is initialized in `app.module.ts` like this:

```
...snipped...

import { AngularFireModule, AuthProviders, AuthMethods } from 'angularfire2';
import { firebaseConfig } from './../environments/firebase.config';
import { FirebaseService } from './services/firebase.service';

...snipped...

const firebaseAuthConfig = {
  provider: AuthProviders.Google,
  method: AuthMethods.Popup
};

...snipped...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...snipped...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, firebaseAuthConfig),
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [FirebaseService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then I use it in my `navbar.component.ts` on a "Login" button like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public af: AngularFire) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  login() {
    this.af.auth.login();
  }

  logou() {
    this.af.auth.logout();
  }

}
```

When I click the login button, the google sign-in popup window opens and closes immediately and I can see the following error in my console:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: A network error (such as
> timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.

Here's the full error message:

[image]

In my Firebase project, I have enabled **Google** as a sign-in provider.

I am aware someone else also had a similar problem [angularfire 2: Error "Unhandled Promise rejection: TypeError: Cannot read property"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38032786/2332336) but their issue was that they were using the old angularfire2/firebase package.

Any ideas why this error might be occurring for me?

Comment: I am only experiencing the issue in Chrome, works fine in FireFox.

Comment: Can you check your chrome console network tab for any network request errors and provide the details?